# Creating COM objects with Java

Tags: java, com

To add support for some new features in a VB3.0 legacy application, I need to create a COM object in Java. I found some tutorials in the Internet, but they all refer to the discontinued javareg.exe tool distributed by Microsoft. I was unable to find a download place nor the MSJVM virtual machine required to run the COM object's code.

So, in nowadays, how can I expose a COM-object written in Java to any other application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the ActiveX Bridge.

> The ActiveX Bridge allow a component
> based on JavaBeans(TM) component
> architecture ("bean") to be
> effectively packaged as an ActiveX
> control, thereby allowing it to be
> used as a functional component in an
> ActiveX container.

The official documentation : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/beans/axbridge/developerguide/index.html

Comment: Where can I find the axbridge? I have installed the jdk1.6.0_24 but don't have the axbridge/bin folder required to build the COM object.

Comment: @Matachana : according to the **doc**, this a default folder. If it's not present maybe you can create it or you can specify another folder with the -out parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. The problem I refer in the comment before is that in my installation, JavaBeans is missing. As I could read in the docs, this must be in the default installation but on my installation all the javabeans related components are missing and because of that I couldn't register the COM class. In order to do that I require the activex/bin folder and its contents to create the bridge and expose the activex class.

Comment: @Matachana : Even it's axbridge is included with Java 6 documentation .. it looks like it's not included anymore. You will have to check previous Java (maybe 1.5 but it's definitely in 1.4.2). According to this thread ( http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1315499&tstart=0 ), it was with jdk1.6_16 but I have jdk1.6_17 and it's not there!?!