# Sending the Certificate Signing Request to CSR in Java

Tags: java, .net, x509certificate

I am trying to migrate a Certification Management tool from .net to Java. I am stuck at the place when we have to get the "Certificate Signing Request" to be signed by CA.

The .net code seems to use a com component to do that.

```
set ICertRequest = Server.CreateObject("CertificateAuthority.Request")
set ICertConfig  = Server.CreateObject("CertificateAuthority.Config") 

ConfigString    = ICertConfig.GetConfig(0)
PKCS10          = request.Form("CertRequest")
SubmitFlag      = request.Form("SubmitFlag")
GetCertFlag     = request.Form("GetCertFlag")
ControlType     = request.Form("ControlType")

DispositionCode = ICertRequest.Submit(SubmitFlag, PKCS10, "", ConfigString)
```

I am trying to find how to do this in Java. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which CA, your own or an external one?  I think you need to know what is signing it before carrying on.

Comment: I dont understand. Are you asking for someone else to port your code for you?

Comment: @Jeff I am asking for Directions. Like we can use "Openssl". The .net code seems to leverage "com" components, I just wanted to know what is the de facto way of doing this in Java.

Comment: @tom It's external CA.

Comment: Ok, so is the question "How can I use a COM component in Java?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669709/creating-com-objects-with-java

Comment: I used to do this years ago and it was horrible in Java.  It's probably improved now, but this might help: http://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/create-x509-certs-in-java

Comment: also, look at the bouncy castle library.  It'll probably make it easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of (unanswered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077767/how-to-sign-x509-certificate-requests-by-using-java-api

Comment: @doc_180 You want to automate signing the CSR?

Comment: In what type of Java Object is your CSR stored? Do you need only  signing the CSR or you want to create the CSR too?